# How to create a controlled form in react that allows upper case letters only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the long explanation, the **question** is at the end.

There is an example given on the reactjs site ( https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html ) that looks like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value.toUpperCase()});
}
```

These tutorials usually say that in controlled forms (say in an input field) when you press a key, then onChange is called, that calls the handleChange event, that calls setState, and that re-renders the component, that will show the changed value. But this is not the whole truth. By the time the native DOM input field calls onChange, the input field was already "rendered" by the browser, and React does not re-render it. Actually it compares the state of the (re-rendered) virtual DOM element with the state of the native DOM element, and then it finds out that there is no difference, so it does nothing. In this case, the action has no side effect (other than changing the component's state).

I know that for a beginner, in the beginning of the tutorial, it may be confusing to tell the whole story at once. But this "toUpperCase()" example in the tutorial is misleading, because it suggests that by changing the value to value.toUpperCase() in handleChange will make the component only accept captialized letters, **without side effects**. But this is not true, and anyone can try this: just select a part of the text in the middle of the input field, and press a key. It will surely be converted to upper case, but in this case React will re-set the value attribute of the input, causing the text cursor (insertion point) to move to the end of the text. Which is a side effect, that can be very distrubing. For example, if the user wanted to replace a word in the middle of the text, then he just can't do it in any practical way. He will say that this is wrong, it is not working - and he will be damn right. In this particular case, I know that I can set text-transform:uppercase and store the lower case version in the store, but that is faulty too: if I need it to be upper case, then of course it should be in upper case in the store. The behaviour of the view must not determine the data representation in the store. Views should only be views, and nothing else.

I have checked many React related tutorials, and all of them have this "flaw". For example, here is a diagram from reactjs.org that shows Flux in action:

[image]

It suggests that the View is rendered **after** the action went through the dispatcher, the stores, then the controller-view. But the reality is that the View not only emits an action. It will also change its appearance **before** the action is emitted. React wants to see DOM elements as views that emit actions, but in reality they do other things.

The very same mistake appears in the reactjs tutorial, with the select element. ( https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html ) They just say that by changing the "multiple={true}" attribute, you can have a multi select. No you can't, it just does not work. When you select multiple items in a multi select, the browser will call the onChange event multiple times: a separate call for every item selected. As a result, it will be impossible to set the state of the component to the set of selected items (at least not from the event handler). I COULD setup a timer, collect all changes emitted from onChange, and the finally call setState() with the collected items. But that is against React's rules, because there should be a single source of truth. And in this case, there will be multiple sources (at least for a while, until all events are collected). And anyone can see that in a complex application with many async handlers, this will eventually lead to bugs which are hard to debug.

A very simple thing ("only accept upper case letters in an input box") appears to me a hard thing to do correctly. Either I have to implement my own input box in JavaScript, or write a custom rendering method for input fields that keeps the cursor position at the correct place when value changes. Both seem to be bad ideas.

After Googling around, I have noticed that there are tons of components re-implementing native elements. There are literally hundreds of select and multiselect components written for React, and I suspect that this is partly because of how native DOM elements behave. (E.g. they are not pure views.)

**Question:** does anyone use react with native DOM components? And if so, how do you achieve the true "controlled" behaviour without the side effects? Is it possible? Or should I not care, and choose some kind of UI toolkit that was written specifically for React? (But even with those, implementing an "upper case input field" may require extra programming.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
handleChange(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  const start = input.selectionStart;
  const end = input.selectionEnd;

  this.setState(
    {value: input.value.toUpperCase()},
    () => input.setSelectionRange(start, end)
  );
}
```

Also check: http://blog.vishalon.net/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: it works for me, but there is simplier solution with just css

Comment: css is the best (text-transform: uppercase), the final text can be capitalized using toUpperCase() before submitting the text to somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

I have written simple `toInputUppercase` function which override `e.target.value` and applied attribute `onInput` to `<input />` element which I want to be capitalize.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const toInputUppercase = e => {
  e.target.value = ("" + e.target.value).toUpperCase();
};

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      value={name}
      onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      onInput={toInputUppercase} // apply on input which do you want to be capitalize
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Works for blank/new inputs. When editing existing values, it sends the cursor to the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this property to the input field :

```
onInput={(e) => e.target.value = ("" + e.target.value).toUpperCase()}
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks -- `e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()` seems to work fine for me too. Why use `("" + )`? Unfortunately, `ctr+z` is broken for me with this solution in Chrome: it moves the cursor to previous position, but does not delete the text.

Comment: Typing anywhere other than at the end of the text also moves the cursor to the end of the text. If you don't want to use the CSS solution `#example {text-transform: uppercase;}` , this is the best JavaScript solution (dynamically moves the cursor on each keypress): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916447/3511695 (`ctrl+z` is broken though)

Answer (score 0):

You are right in what you observe but the issue does not come from React, it comes from the browser itself.

Consider the following example:

```js
function handler() {
  const elt = document.getElementById('test');
  elt.value = elt.value.toUpperCase();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="test" type="text" value="default value" onKeyPress="handler();" />
</body>
</html>
```

How would you make it work even before talking about React ? React can't override the browser behavior.

If you want to uppercase everything while keeping the cursor position, you could  look at rich text editing with draft js for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all recommended to call toUpperCase() on every change event, because if you understand the inner working of the toUpperCase() function, it loops over the char array of the string and looping takes a time of O(n), hence when the loop is ongoing another onchange will be called and because of this sometimes it shows unexpected behaviour and you won't get expected result. The issue i faced was that it was appending the new input to the previous input. The best solution for this is to Convert the string to Uppercase whenever user leaves the focus of the input, i.e. you can use onBlur() event and convert the string to uppercase whenver blur event is triggered, hence the touppercase will be called only one time and will give the expected result

Comment: Converting a string (found in a simple input box) is not CPU bound. It takes less than 1ms to do the conversion on any CPU. The question was not about optimizing for CPU usage. Your suggestion about converting to upper case after leaving the input field is valid, but I think that was not the point of the question. The question was to find the best approach for abstracting away the actual browser behaviour, and build up a mental model that is closer to reality than the "advertised" uni-directional flow, but still allows a high level of abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

easy: css + normalization (`toUpperCase()`) after submit

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: Please look at the original question: "I know that I can set text-transform:uppercase and store the lower case version in the store, but that is faulty too: if I need it to be upper case, then of course it should be in upper case in the store." The question was not "how to display the stored value so that it looks like it is in upper case". The question was about creating a solution that stores converted (upper case) values in the store.. That would work with ANY conversion function (for example, capitalize etc.)

Comment: // excuse my beginner's English.


I understand it initially. Let's I clarify a bit. You can separate react+css displaying and working with server. So let's react works with lower or any user inputed case, but just add .toUpperCase() to formatter before ajax request function.